# Sql query : For each letter of the alphabet, looking for how many suburbs begin with that letter

Tags: mysql, sql

The given table  is  as :

```
Postcode   _______SuburbName 
一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一
3011 ____________Footscray 
3045____________Asco
3088____________Highpoint
 .........
一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一一
```

the answer can be like :

```
A 3
B 6
.........
Z 4
一一一一一一一一一一一一一
```

and just skip letters with a count of zero.....

Thanks a lot for your time  :)

Comment: SUBSTR to get first character. Do GROUP BY with COUNT.

Comment: Please edit your question so it's "body" contains the actual question. The headline should hold a short summary like "Sum of all rows beginning with the same letter"

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `LEFT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to extract the first letter, [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) to know how many there are, and [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to have a count for each letter:

```
SELECT LEFT(SuburbName, 1) AS letter, COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM my_table
GROUP BY letter
```